# Azure Logic App Service Bus connection returning empty Body

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, servicebus

I've set up an Azure Logic App that is supposed to go to my service bus and peak at the messages in one of my Topics. The Logic App then parses the response, counts the messages in the Topic, and updates a database which I'm then using in a BI report to show the message count.

Logic App workflow:

[image: logic]

The process works fine, but frequently the service bus step is returning an empty body response which I know is wrong. Here's what the results look like:

Graphical results of the logic app:

[image: graphical]

The messages aren't being added and processed at this rate, so the empty body response is clearly wrong.

I have the logic app set up to run every 3 minutes, could this be affecting the results, or is the Service Bus step timing out?

Or is something else going wrong here?